# Creating an algorithm in my constructor for a deck

Tags: java, algorithm

An assignment for school requires me to create a deck of cards and soon we will doing things to the deck like drawing from it and all sorts of things. I want to use an ArrayList for the job but the first time I wrote the constructor for the deck, it was very long and drawn out. The deck contains cards that have a color and an animal with two copies of each card. Does anyone have an efficient algorithm for filling the ArrayList?

EDIT: My apologies for the lack of details. Basically we just need to create a deck with a bunch of cards that each have a color and an animal. Here, the colors used are red,blue, and black. The animals are lion, tiger, and bear. This is what I wrote so far but it is for an array only so I would have to adapt it for the ArrayList:

```
public Deck() {
    //fills with blank cards
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        d[i] = new Card();
    }
    //adds color to cards first
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        d[i].setColor("red");
    }
    for (int i = 6; i <= 11; i++) {
        d[i].setColor("blue");
    }
    for (int i = 12; i <= 17; i++) {
        d[i].setColor("black");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if ((d[i].getColor().equals("red")) && (i % 3 == 0)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("lion");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("red") && (i % 3 == 1)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("tiger");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("red") && (i % 3 == 2)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("bear");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("blue") && (i % 3 == 0)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("lion");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("blue") && (i % 3 == 1)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("tiger");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("blue") && (i % 3 == 2)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("bear");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("black") && (i % 3 == 0)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("lion");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("black") && (i % 3 == 1)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("tiger");
        } else if (d[i].getColor().equals("black") && (i % 3 == 2)) {
            d[i].setAnimal("bear");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post what you wrote so far.

Comment: How did you want to fill it? What did you try to do? Why is this solution not good enough?

Comment: Off the top of my head, a 'card' type with enums for colors and animals, and a nested loop to hit all possible combinations.  But a little more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing 4 different loops , use 1 loop to set both colour and animal .

You can even use a single loop and write a switch statement to set both colour and animal.

```
List<Card> cards= new ArrayList<Card>();
for( int i=0; i < length; i++ ){
     Card = new Card();
     animal=i%3;
     switch(animal):
       //set the animal based on value of switch
      colour =i%4;
     swicth(colour)
       //set the colour of the card 

     cards.add(card);

}
```

Also your deck object should have a referrence to list of cards and other functions needed to implement it. Deck object should not be just a list of cards.For ex you should not create

```
List<Card> Deck=new ArrayList<Card>();
```